# Bot not finding member. (Discord.JS V13)

Tags: discord.js

So, I made a command which sends you a DM with a button, in this case, a captcha button. After you press the button, it goes into a guild and searches for you inside of it so it can give you a role.

```
let gn = bot.guilds.cache.get('906210773989203990');
let member = gn.members.cache.find(x => x.id == interaction.user.id);
member.roles.add(role.id);
```

Whenever I try to console.log member, it returns undefined. (and yes, I have already tried logging interaction.user.id and it works fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The member is not found in the cache, but you can fetch the member

```js
let member = await gn.members.fetch(interaction.user.id)
```

But simply using `interaction.member` is much better

```js
let member = interaction.member
```

Comment: It works :). And no, I can't use interaction.member since the interaction was executed in a DM.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but try to replace your `let member = gn.members.cache.find(x => x.id == interaction.user.id);` with `let member = gn.members.cache.fetch(interaction.user.id);`

Comment: Doesn't work. "gn.members.cache.fetch is not a function"